# How to remove the minimize button completely from all the modules

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have build a container in which I have removed all the Visibility tags, and compiled the container and uploaded it to my site. But I'm still getting the minimize button. I do not know what could've possibly gone wrong. This is my sample code.

```xml
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True"    Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONS" Src="~/Admin/Containers/SolPartActions.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ICON" Src="~/Admin/Containers/Icon.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TITLE" Src="~/Admin/Containers/Title.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONBUTTON"  Src="~/Admin/Containers/ActionButton.ascx" %>
<%--@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="VISIBILITY" Src="~/Admin/Containers/Visibility.ascx" --%>
<div class="c_container">
<div class="c_content_inner">

        <div class="c_actions">
            <dnn:ACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnACTIONS"  ProviderName="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" ExpandDepth="1" PopulateNodesFromClient="True" />
        </div>
        <div class="c_icon">            
            <dnn:ICON runat="server" id="dnnICON"  />
        </div>

        <div id="ContentPane" runat="server">

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="c_footer">
        <dnn:ACTIONBUTTON runat="server" id="dnnACTIONBUTTON1"  CommandName="AddContent.Action" DisplayIcon="True" DisplayLink="True" />
        <dnn:ACTIONBUTTON runat="server" id="dnnACTIONBUTTON2"  CommandName="SyndicateModule.Action" DisplayIcon="True" DisplayLink="false" />
        <dnn:ACTIONBUTTON runat="server" id="dnnACTIONBUTTON4"  CommandName="ModuleSettings.Action" DisplayIcon="True" DisplayLink="false" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the container side, your approach is correct. As you did, you just remove the visibility control from the container. My guess is that DNN isn't configured to use that container. To change the container used for the portal, go to Admin -> Site Settings -> Appearance and change the selection for the Containers to your modified container.

If that doesn't work, the container can also be set at the module level through the module settings and it can also be specified in the skin.

Good Luck!